# Building from source ,perl ruby lua and python support are not activating, why?

Tags: linux, compile-vim

Here are the things I have :

The configure snippet I am using :

```
./configure  --with-features=huge --enable-rubyinterp=yes --with-ruby-command=/usr/bin/ruby ---enable-pythoninterp=yes --with-python-config-dir=$(python3-config --configdir) --enable-python3interp=yes --enable-perlinterp=yes --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --enable-luainterp=yes --with-luajit  --enable-multibyte --enable-fontset --enable-largefile --prefix=/usr --enable-fail-if-missing
```

Here are few things:

```
Here are evidence that requires stuff is installed:

% whereis perl
perl: /usr/bin/perl /usr/share/man/man1/perl.1.bz2

% whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby /usr/lib64/ruby /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1

% whereis lua
lua: /usr/bin/lua /usr/lib64/lua /usr/share/lua

% whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1

% whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3
```

Wondering ..what is causing it to fail :

```
% v --version | ack lua
+cursorbind -lua +scrollbind +wildmenu

% v --version | ack ruby
+cscope +localmap -ruby +wildignore

% v --version | ack perl
+byte_offset +insert_expand -perl +title

% v --version | ack python
+cmdline_hist +langmap -python +viminfo
+cmdline_info +libcall -python3 +virtualedit
```

Please enlighten me!

Comment: The `./configure` output and `src/auto/config.log` should have the reason why it didn't select the Python, Perl, etc. interface. Usually the problem is that development headers aren't present on the system and you need to install a `python3-devel` package or the like, but I'm not familiar with Gentoo specifically. Most (or all?) of the language interfaces don't use the "python" or "lua" command, but link against libpython, liblua, etc.

Comment: Check the [faq](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-35.10)